# How to estimate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\log\log2)^n/n! $ from below?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms

How to show that the following inequality holds:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}>\frac 35$$

Is it possible to prove this using induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: what is $\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$? Then plug $x=\log\log2$.

Comment: Will the inequality remain true the above series is converging to $e^{(loglog2)}$ which is not $> 3/5$@Milly

Comment: @learningmaths Check you calculations: it is greater than $3/5$. Do you use the correct base of logarithm? It should be $e$, the logarithm is $\ln $, the natural logarithm. You can simplify things a bit: $e^{\ln y}=y$.

Comment: Ya sorry I got it wrong thanx for the correction@CareBear

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't know what $\sum\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is, the first two terms give $1+\log\log2\approx0.63\ldots>\frac35$. Since this is an alternating series and $1+\log\log2$ is a partial sum ending on a negative term, whatever the sum is it will be greater than that $0.63\ldots$.

Comment: Will you please explain how did you get sure that the sum is >0.63

Comment: You need to note that $\log\log2$ is negative, and less than $1$ in absolute value. So then the terms $(\log\log2)^n/n!$ are alternating in sign, and getting smaller in absolute value. Series like this one have this pattern: $$\mbox{initial positive term}-\mbox{something smaller}+\mbox{something yet smaller}-\mbox{something even more smaller}+\cdots$$ If you cut this at a partial sum right after a subtraction, the subsequent terms will _never_ amount to enough to take you lower than that partial sum.

Comment: Sir I want justification of your last comment ..."lower that partial sum"

Comment: I have justified it, but you don't understand yet. Read anywhere online or in a calculus textbook about the alternating series test, and then go into examples of alternating series estimation.

Comment: See [here](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/altser/altser.html) and note in the picture how the zigzags never dip lower than the first dip.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation .It has helped me